# Is my demand for a raise reasonable?

Tags: salary, raise

I graduated about 8 months ago from a 4 years art program and I just finished a 6 month contract  as a 2D Videogame Artist in Toronto. At the time I was quite happy (and intimidated) to state what kind of salary I was expecting so I left them give me an offer which was 30K annually.

Very early on I not only exceeded expectations but thanks to my studies in my field and knowledge of various programs I was able to produce much more elaborate work than they were used to before my arrival. I did work that would not only suit a 2D Artist but also a Motion Designer,2D Animator and was given a rather large autonomy creative wise to do these tasks.

I am not the kind to care much about money nor to be resented by it, but I did feel after several months that I could be paid more for what I brought to the table.

So today was a meeting with my supervisor and I believe someone in charge of finances and they announced me that they want to extend my contract for another 6 months. The discussion of a raise did not come up until he asked if I had any questions, to which I asked if it would be possible to revise my salary. He asked me what I was number I was thinking of and I replied "40,000 annually".

I came to that number by doing some researches about Junior 2D artist salaries as well as the other jobs I felt I was doing for them, plus the fact that I currently do not have paid vacation times or sick days and the feeling that I really do my best not only to produce quality work, but to constantly improve my abilities as well.

This is my first salary talk experience so I am a bit nervous thinking back on the whole thing. Am I way out of line here? Your thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to the site @SugK. Your question is too specific to your situation for it to be a valid fit for our Q&A format and has been closed accordingly. Have a look at this question for tips on negotiating salary: [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid). If you want to discuss specifics you'd be best served by asking in our chatroom. If you'd like to discuss it there, reply and I'll ask a mod to grant you access (joining chat requires 20 reputation).

Answer (score 6):

It is never out of line to ask for a raise if you're productive and feel you're worth it. The worst that can happen is that they say no. The best is that they give it, but more likely they will give a counter offer and you can negotiate from there.

Your contract is ending, you're not obligated to continue it under the same conditions and from what you have said you deserve more. I would have asked for more and settled on 40K.

Comment: Yes it is never out of the question to ask for a raise but to add to this post I would like to say always bring to the table what you did and why you feel you deserve a raise. Make a list of things you did prior to your review/negotiations so you can bring them up during the process. That will increase your chances since it'll remind them of what you did.

Comment: yes, a gentle reminder would be good, from the OP's post they're already aware of a few things, but no harm driving the point home to them.